# It won't override class

Tags: css

If user didn't enter the fields properly, it will show the error message with `class="ErrorInput"` and `class="TextError"`.

I am having a problem with `ErrorInput` class, when it has been defined in the html tag - it will not override the default input class.

**HTML**:

```
<li>
  <label>First Name</label>
   <input type="text" value="" class="ErrorInput" name="firstname">
   <div class="TextError">Please enter First Name</div>  
</li>
<li>
   <label>Second Name</label>
   <input type="text" value="Gates" name="secondname">
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.FormStyle .ErrorInput {
    border: #AD2930;
}

.FormStyle input[type=text], .FormStyle textarea {
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 290px;
    border: 1px solid #BDC7D8;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure(maybe it is not necessary) but you are missing closing tags of `input` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `border-colour` for the input in both `.FormStyle .ErrorInput` and `.FormStyle input[type=text]`

As `.FormStyle input[type=text]` is more specific than `.FormStyle .ErrorInput`, the `#BDC7D8` colour is applied.

You will need to make the first CSS selector more specific for it to override the second colour:

```
.FormStyle input[type=text].ErrorInput {
    border-color: #AD2930;
}
```

Learn more about specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the border correctly:

```
.FormStyle .ErrorInput {
    border: 1px solid #AD2930;
}
```

And this css part must be placed **after** the input styling